# c++/cli delegates + lambda + overload funcions

Tags: c++-cli

I haven't any idea about how to do the same in c++/cli.
Is not clear for me how a I can create delegate and how I can invoke it.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

```
    public class Writer {

    internal Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> Reflective = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    public Writer()
    {
        Reflective.Add(typeof(float), (value) => Write((float)value));
        Reflective.Add(typeof(double), (value) => Write((double)value));
    }

    public void Write(float value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Float");
    }

    public void Write(double value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Double");
    }

    public void Write<T>(T[] values)
    {
        var method = this.Reflective[typeof(T)];
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            method(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegates are covered in any introductory book about C++/CLI programming, we can't help you make the trip to your local library.  If you need somebody to translate the code for you then consider rentacoder.com

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the whole thing for you, but here's a couple of the non-obvious things to get you started:

```
typeof(float) ==> System::Single::typeid
// I like to specify the full namespace for explicitness.
```

Lambdas: C++/CLI does not support lambdas. You'll need to declare a full-fledged method, and construct a delegate to that. Fortunately, you already have that, your two Write methods should work. Don't forget when declaring the delegate, if it's an instance method, you'll need to specify the object to invoke the function on, which should be `this` in your code.